Why did substantial portion of "democracy" voters vote for Trump?
When I first saw these exit polls, I was a bit surprised. Democracy + Abortion voters¹ outnumbered Immigration + Economy voters, so Harris's coalition should've performed better.
However, when I looked closer at the numbers, I noticed something unexpected: a fifth of Democracy voters voted for Trump (who was widely perceived as a threat to democracy in the context of January 6). While it's complex and it would be wrong to pin the outcome to one single factor, if none of the Democracy voters voted for Trump, Harris's coalition would indeed be winning (by a lot). It doesn't necessarily mean she'd win (considering the electoral college), but at least she would be much more likely to win the popular vote.
Here's the breakdown. FP – foreign policy, A – abortion, E – economy, I – immigration, D – democracy. The multiplier is the share of issue voters that voted for the candidate, the multiplicand is the share of overall voters who believe the issue to be the most important one (in percentage points).

Harris
FP: 0.37×4 +
A: 0.74×14 +
E: 0.19×32 +
I: 0.09×11 +
D: 0.8×34
= 46.11


Trump
FP: 0.57×4 +
A: 0.25×14 +
E: 0.8×32 +
I: 0.9×11 +
D: 0.18×34
= 47.4


Harris (all D)
FP: 0.37×4 +
A: 0.74×14 +
E: 0.19×32 +
I: 0.09×11 +
D: 1×34
= 61.82


Trump (no D)
FP: 0.57×4 +
A: 0.25×14 +
E: 0.8×32 +
I: 0.9×11 +
D: 0×34
= 41.28

A few more details I found interesting:

Slightly more than half of respondents that believe the US democracy is threatened (73%) voted for Trump. It's as if those voters for some reason perceived Harris to be a greater threat to democracy than Trump.

Most respondents believe Trump is "too extreme" (54%), 12% of those (6% of total) cast the ballot for Trump anyway. It implies a noticeable portion of Trump voters don't mind or even welcome him being "extreme" (which is not typically associated with respecting democratic institutions). That said, it doesn't mean "extreme Trump voters" and "democracy voters" intersect a lot.


So the question is, why did a substantial portion of Democracy voters vote for Trump? Were any theories put forward by scholars, political analysts?
¹ Voters who believe the issue to be the most important one (see "Most important issue" on the linked page). For example, "Abortion voters" believe abortion is the most important issue

One question to keep in mind, when those people say they care about preserving democracy, are they talking about preserving it from a president unwilling to accept election results, or preserving it from a party stealing the vote. It wouldn't surprise me if a fair amount of Trump's base sincerely believe he was democratically elected and the election somehow got stolen. If someone believes that, then obviously they'd need to vote for Trump in order to safeguard democracy.

Also important to note how the question was phrased when asked to voters: "Do you think democracy in the U.S. today is:" with the options: Very secure | Secure | Somewhat Secure | Somewhat Threatened | Threatened | Very Threatened. As with all opinion polling, you get an answer, but you don't necessarily know how the subject interpreted the question.

First, calling people 'democracy voters' is thoroughly unhelpful. From reading you link it seems this refers to the question "Do you think democracy in the U.S. today is secure/ threatened". The results of this question are 50/50, there is no correlation in any direction. The only meaning of this result is that someones answer to this question doesn't tell you anything about how they voted.

What on earth are "democracy voters"??

@user182601 voters who believe democracy to be the most important issue (see "Most important issue" on the linked page)

Trump (who was widely perceived as a threat to democracy in the context of January 6) - how "widely" was Trump perceived as a threat to democracy? The numbers may well align with the numbers of 'democracy' voters that voted for him.

The "threat to democracy" line was a particular favorite of Democrat politicians and those sympathetic them, but once it started, it was used in both directions.  It is not reasonable to assume that voters who thought democracy threatened were necessarily anti-Trump.

As well as the many other good points it's important to note that many on the right see the whole "cancel culture" think as an assault on democracy in general and the First Amendment in particular.

Well for one thing they probably believe, as he claims, that he is the target of a witch-hunt with all these court cases against him, and for another thing, there were two attempts to assassinate him. Presumably they see both or either of these as undemocratic or threats to democracy.

These FP, A, E abbreviations make your figures unreadable.  Why not spell them out?

It’s safe to say that at least  twenty percent of Americans viewed the Democrats and some of the anti-Trump efforts as threats to democracy that needed to be counteracted by electing Trump.
The January 6 committee was probably the most notable anti-Trump effort that argued he  is a threat to democracy. According to most polls a very large percent of Americans viewed it with suspicion. This  ABC poll is consistent with the election results. It indicates that  about twenty percent of Americans said the J6 committee made them more likely to vote Republican (though  not necessarily Trump)
https://www.ipsos.com/sites/default/files/ct/news/documents/2022-06/Topline%20ABC_Ipsos%20Poll%20June%2018%202022.pdf
That is but one example. In general Republican voters were slightly more concerned than Democrat voters  about the future of the democracy if the other party wins
https://apnorc.org/projects/widespread-feeling-that-the-2024-presidential-election-carries-serious-stakes-for-the-country/
Back when RFK jr was still running as an independent against both Biden and Trump, his campaign rhetoric  was that Biden is a bigger threat to democracy than Trump
https://www.cnn.com/2024/04/01/politics/rfk-jr-cnntv-interview/index.html
Trump frequently campaigned as the  defender of democracy. He referred to the assassination attempt on him as “taking a bullet for democracy". His supporters believed that the department of Justice has been weaponized  etc.

I wouldn't name it "anti-Trump effort", but "pro-democracy effort".

@U.Windl would you be open to call it "anti-democracy effort"? Because there are people who do. In light of this thought do you think neutral name is more appropriate here?

@U.Windl: When discussing different viewpoints, and settling a question of fact for a wide audience, it’s much more useful to use terms that everyone can agree on (like “pro-/anti-Trump” or “pro-/anti-Harris”) rather than terms like “pro-democracy” that different people will interpret in contradictory ways.  Personally I fully agree that the “anti-Trump” efforts are also “pro-democracy”, but calling them that here would obscure the point at hand.

The problem is that these two groups likely don't agree on the "threats to democracy".
For Democrats the threats to democracy have more to do with Trump eroding longstanding traditions, safeguards and checks and balances. Starting by not releasing his tax returns, not putting his assets in a blind trust to avoid personal enrichment, using pardons as get out of jail free cards for doing crime in his favor and often even advertising that, replacing long lasting judge positions with ideological figures who might be more inclined to him than the law and could be pardoned if charged, having put in place Supreme Court justices that declared the president basically above the law, the unwillingness to let any of Trump's scandals and even crimes have any consequences, on top of persistent problems like voter suppression, gerrymandering, the electoral college and so on.
While on the other hand Trump and the conservative groups that back him have made the case of election fraud (leading to Jan 6), of illegal voting, of suppression of free speech. Now there have no substantial evidence been submitted for election fraud and given the stats and the rarity of illegal voting, it's often conjectured that it's more of an attempt to make voting harder and thus suppress the vote of minorities. And conservatives own a large share of the media landscape of the U.S.; Musk recently bought Twitter and turned it into a right wing echo chamber.
But just because you can reasonably object to these claims doesn't mean there aren't people who would look at those issues and tick a box named "do you see a threat to the democracy" with "yes".

"no substantial evidence": for people living in an ideological bubble, the claim itself is frequently evidence enough.

Trump and his crew are not conservative, so not sure why you write about conservatives in the third paragraph.  They have explicitly stated they seek radical reforms, which is inherently anti-conservative.  Therefore, what conservatives want is irrelevant to the question.

@phoog Do you mean to say there was relevant evidence? If yes, would you mind sharing it / sources to it, please?

@phoog I mean it's rarely stated and "freedom of religion" gives some loopholes, but the premise of a society is kinda that people live in the same measurable reality and that they can agree on facts even if they disagree on priorities, preferences, significance, conclusions, etc. But sure being divorced from reality is an out, but also creates much bigger problems...

@gerrit https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_Revolution Wouldn't be the first time for conservatives to do that. Like seriously no conservative party ever has actually just conserved something they all had some reactionary (backwards facing) ideal that they aimed for (think of the 2nd A in MAGA...). Also I haven't said that he is conservative, but that conservatives back him, isn't that the case?

@haxor789 True, some conservatives back him, others consider him dangerous.  IMO "conservative revolution" misuses the term, but I fear continuing this discussion will run into a "no true scotsman" fallacy on my side, so I will stop here.

"replacing long lasting judge positions with ideological figures" is absolutely something both parties have done, so if that's enough for someone to tick "democracy is threatened", you already have the answer of why Trump voters would answer the survey that way

@FrancoisTheFrenchOne no, there is no evidence.  I'm just saying that people who are convinced something is true don't typically require real evidence.  If someone makes an unsupported claim that comports with their understanding of how the world works and how things are, they frequently take the claim as sufficient evidence in its own right.  I read a couple of months ago some woman being interviewed at a Trump rally saying in all seriousness "he wouldn't say these things if they weren't true."

@jwenting every video I've seen that purports to show something like "truckloads of ballots being delivered to counting stations days after the polls closed" turned out to be completely unsupportive of accusations or fraud but rather showed normal procedure.  Links, please.

@haxor789 "the premise of a society is kinda that people live in the same measurable reality and that they can agree on facts even if they disagree on priorities, preferences, significance, conclusions, etc": unfortunately, US society (among others) has abandoned this premise almost entirely over the last couple of decades.

@phoog guess that depends on which cuts you get to see, which depends on where you see them.

@jwenting no, it's not about the editing of the video; it's about people utterly misunderstanding or misrepresenting the significance of the things being shown in the video.  For example, a video  showing ballots being delivered to a counting center days after the election doesn't say anything about whether or when those ballots were counted.

This is kind of covered by other answers, but I'll summarize here:

There are many people (especially Trump voters) who do NOT consider Trump a threat to democracy.

A whole book can be written on reasoning, but I'll just give the most pithy rejoinder: "If Trump is such a democracy hating dictator, why did none of the fascist stuff happen when he had first 4 years as President?".
And calling election stolen and not accepting election results happened on Democratic party side for ages, at least since 2000 elections all the way through 2016 "not my president" stuff. You don't get to single out 2020 as uniquely bad but hypocritically ignore 2000, 2016 and likely other less egregious examples. FFS, I just saw a compilation reel of left wingers complaining about "rigged/stolen election" in 2024.


There are many people (especially Trump voters) who think that Democratic party is the main threat to democracy, in 2024 (just as Democratic People's Republic of Korea is neither Democratic, People's or Republic :) . Again, the reasoning of people like that would take a book to explain, but can probably be condensed into several pillars of concern; among them:

Misuse of government to persecute political opponents. And this is NOT just about attacks on Trump as a person. This started with using IRS to harass conservatives during Obama era

in all fairness, this started with Proscriptions in ancient Rome. Or probably/likely with cavemen
But yes, attacks on Trump REALLY didn't help this impression. Don't forget, voters severely punished Republicans when they persecuted Clinton "for sex" (the fact that it was for what today would be called an extreme case of sexual harrassment, is doubly ironic. The fact that Lewinsky scandal came out of financial investigations into cattle trading, is triply ironic).


Constant talk about court packing, FDR style
Overall philosophy of the left, which values giving more power to the government at the expense of the people
Attacks on 2d amendment, which the opponents view as integral to freedom and democracy
Attacks on 1st amendment (both related to language policing, and far more dangerously, to speech suppression under Biden done by, or on behalf, of government).
Use of Executive orders and general expansion of Executive power

Ironically, this is factually wrong on a tactical level - Bush signed slightly more EOs than Obama and Trump more than Biden - BUT, if you look at a trend for the party as a whole, the champ is FDR who probably signed more than Bush, Obama, Biden and Trump combined, and Democrats overall signed far more than Republicans on average since 1900


Use of illegal immigrants to affect voting - either actual illegal voting (the argument being, why is it OK to demand ID to drive, fly on a plane, visit a concert, buy beer BUT suddenly an onerous requirement to do so to vote?), OR, simply efforts to legalize illegal immigrants so they can vote legally.
The fact that 90%+ (or 99%) of mass media is solidly pro-Democractic-Party and anti-Trump. As well as most social media platforms. Now, the media being partisan isn't new, it started in 1700s or at least early 1800s. But it being overwhelmingly partisan one way, is new and considered undemocratic by many.



Also, to add a more personal content, your user name makes me suspect you're from Russia. Think about this in terms of Yeltzin. Yes, he was a "threat to democracy" when he literally had military attack Parlament in 1993 (ironically called White House :)  Yet many people thought that the people in that Parlament were a bigger threat to democracy than whatever Yeltzin did

I left the assasination attempts on Trump off the list, since I'm not certain many people considered them to be "threat to democracy" related to election per se. A reason to vote for Trump - maybe. But I'm not aware than many tied it to "threat to democracy" angle.

While I consider a number of points made in this answer manipulative or plainly false, it provides a good dive into reasoning of Trump voters and fits the question well. Thanks

Two big points, the rigged 2016 primary and the lack of a primary in 2024 are also viewed as threatening to democracy by many.

@DavidS - technically true and a great point, but I suspect very few Trump voters have strong feelings about Dem primaries (or superdelegates). I mean poly sci nerds like me might - regardless of which side they are on - but few people care about 2016 primaries except Dems who liked Bernie, IMHO

I think the title of this Q has a wrong assumption, essentially implying that being worried about a threat to democracy was a cause of voting for Trump. The survey only shows that Trump voters also went higher on the "democracy in danger" item, which is a standard correlation thing -- we can't say one caused the other. In fact, I don't think a threat to democracy was in the top two reasons people gave. A better way to put the question is "why did people who voted for Trump (for reasons we don't need to know) also pick higher on that survey item?"
Something I've been hearing, more-or-less for years, is that Trump voters aren't giving their real opinions. You may recall in the 2016 election the polls underestimating Trump were explained as Trump voters being either embarrassed ("he's a horrible person, but he'd do good things") or disliking pollsters. But either way, Trump voters were known for being close-mouthed. This year the idea is people don't want to say their real reason, or if they even had one. They don't want to say aloud that they don't think a women is tough enough, or Trump will do a good job since he's a businessman, or they're uncomfortable with transgenders, or they thought he was cool on the Joe Rogan show. Which is fair. My honest answer to why I voted for Harris would have to be a less-than-flattering "I always vote Democratic". I'm real tempted to say "wait, what are the cool-sounding options again?"

This doesn’t answer the question of why they voted the way they did

@JoeW Hmmm...to me the question is obviously "why did Trump voters say this on the survey". That's the question I'm answering, and I think it's the right question to ask. But the title of this Q is the other way around. I don't think a single person said "I'm worried about Democracy, so ... Trump or Harris?" but it's still something I should be more explicit about.

The way I read it is you are simply stating that they are not actually saying they are voting for Trump let alone stating why they are voting for him. There are many reasons why this could be and the simple one is that they don't want to admit that they support Trump for any reason at all. You seem to be making assumptions about why they are doing it.

@JoeW I hope the new leading P clears it up. I'm a little offended you think "I'm" making assumptions -- I feel like I'm reminding people of the widespread agreement after the bad 2016 polls, about the "shy" Trump voter. But I understand the culture here is that you just made it up unless you link to something even if it hurts readability, so I'm not really offended.

"I think the title of this Q has a wrong assumption, essentially implying that being worried about a threat to democracy was a cause of voting for Trump." No, I was wondering why those voters voted for Trump in spite of being allegedly worried about democracy more than any other issue

@SergeyZolotarev Saying that it's the wrong Q is an accepted thing here. It's broadly known as a Frame Challenge if you want to look it up. I assumed everyone has heard "correlation is not causation" a hundred times, so didn't go into it. Sorry if you haven't heard it, but looking it up gives decent results.

I never implied any causation at all

Somewhat unrelated, but if you look at Poly Sci research, I think something like 60-80% of voters (of both parties) literally do the same thing you say you are ashamed for (vote 100% for the party, regardless of who the candidate is). Ironically, many people voted for Trump for either same reason, or a twist of "don't care how bad Trump is as a person, Democratic party is a worse of two evils").

@user4012 Absolutely, detailed survey Q's will typically have fluffy results because people are rating "worried about X" who didn't think about it for second when they voted; which OP seems to be discounting. But at least we're comparing Apples-to-Apples. My point is with "shy" Trump voters it's more like Apple to Oranges.

@OwenReynolds - I'd never IRL admit to voting for ANYONE right wing (Trump or not) because I literally am afraid for both my life and livelyhood at this point. Unlike left wingers in USA, I remember 50 (or 100 depending on methodology) million that socialists murdered last century. And I grew up in USSR, I know the nature of the enemy. I feel literally the same social/political vibes in 2024 USA as in USSR. The only reason I do so on SE is because I am supposedly anonymous here.
